# Pass variables into parent's constructor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to pass through variables from a child class to the parent's constructor.

The parent class' constructor consists of `(Context!, String!, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory!, Int)`.

I can easily do

```
class TodoListDBHandler(context: Context, databaseName: String, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, databaseVersion: Int): 
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, databaseName, factory, databaseVersion)
```

but I would like to specify the database name and version directly inside the class instead of specifying it every time I call the constructor as I might make mistakes.

My current code:

```
class TodoListDBHandler(context: Context, databaseName: String, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, databaseVersion: Int): 
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, databaseName, factory, databaseVersion) {

    val databaseFileName = "todoList.db"
    val databaseVersion = 1

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

As stated above, I would like to be able to pass in the variable I have specified to the parent's constructor.

EDIT: This is the desired code, but in Java

```java
public TodoListDBHandler(Context context, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
    // databaseFileName and databaseVersion are already specified inside the class
    super(context, databaseFileName, factory, databaseVersion)
}
```

Comment: Even in Java this is only possible if databaseFileName and databaseVersion are static field. The constructor of the super class is always called before any initialisation of the derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@farhanjk gives a good solution, but you can also put them into the companion object:

```
class TodoListDBHandler(context: Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory): 
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, TodoListDBHandler.databaseName, factory, TodoListDBHandler.databaseVersion) {

    companion object {
        val databaseFileName = "todoList.db"
        val databaseVersion = 1
    }

    ...
}
```

This can be useful e.g. if there is non-trivial initialization or to create a list just once, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the constant arguments directly in the super class constructor.

```
class TodoListDBHandler(context: Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)
        : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "todoList.db", factory, 1) {

        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        }

        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        }
}
```